Blazor Server app and Microsoft Entra ID authorization by role
I have a Blazor Server application and its Microsoft Entra ID authentication is working but I cannot set up authorization in my app. I have created a role in the App registrations > App roles > Users/Group. And I have added myself to this role: Enterprise applications > Users and groups > Add Assignment.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
  // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
  //options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
  options.AddPolicy("RequireUserRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Officer"));
});

I tried tu set policy according to this article but not success.
I want to secure the whole site like this in MainLayout.razor:
<AuthorizeView Policy="RequireUserRole">
    <Authorized>
        <MudMainContent Style="background-color:--mud-palette-background-grey;">
            @Body
        </MudMainContent>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <MudMainContent Style="background-color:--mud-palette-background-grey;">
            <p>No authorized</p>
        </MudMainContent>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

But authorization fails.
